# How to display video after getting from json?

Tags: android, json, android-videoview

I am getting json response perfectly,but I want to display video which i get from json in my video view but its not showing..my response is give below..and my snippet code and also UI design view..can any one help?

[image]

**json**

```
   {        
     "user_login_id":"2650",    
     "user_total_video":"0",  
     "max_upload_video":"1",  
     "video_id":"485",  
     "video_status":"Approved",  
     "video":"http:\/\/lakinos.com\/uploads\/user\/1249\/small\/Denger.3gp"  
    }
```

**java**

```
 public class VideoList extends Activity{
private String User_IDs;
private String total;
private String max;
private String vidid;
private String vidsta;
private String vd;
private VideoView vides;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private ImageAdapter adapter;
private Button btnvideoupload;
private Button btndelete;
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

 private static final String DELT_SETPRO_URL = "";
private static final String DELT_SETPRO_STATUS = "status";
private static final String DELT_SETPRO_MSG = "msg";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fullvideo);
    User_IDs=this.getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
    System.out.println("photo upload view user id"+User_IDs);

    total=this.getIntent().getStringExtra("totalvideos");
    System.out.println("photo total "+total);

    max=this.getIntent().getStringExtra("maxvideos");
    System.out.println("photo maximum "+max);

    vidid=this.getIntent().getStringExtra("videoid");
    System.out.println("photo maximum "+vidid);

    vidsta=this.getIntent().getStringExtra("vidstatus");
    System.out.println("photo maximum "+vidsta);

    vd=this.getIntent().getStringExtra("vids");
    System.out.println("photo maximum "+vd);

    btnvideoupload=(Button)findViewById(R.id.goforuploadvid);

    btnvideoupload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),VideoUpload.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", User_IDs);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    btndelete=(Button)findViewById(R.id.deletevid);
    btndelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            new AttemptLogin().execute();
        }
    });

    }

      //Creating MediaController  
/*MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(this);  
   mediaController.setAnchorView(vides); 
    Uri uri=Uri.parse(vd.toString()); 
    vides.setVideoURI(uri);
    vides.setMediaController(new MediaController(VideoList.this));
    vides.requestFocus();*/

    }

public void getInit() 
{ 
    vides=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoviewfull);

    //video_player_view = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_player_view);
    mediaController = new MediaController(this); 
    dm = new DisplayMetrics(); 
    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    int height = dm.heightPixels; 
    int width = dm.widthPixels; 
    vides.setMinimumWidth(width); 
    vides.setMinimumHeight(height); 
    vides.setMediaController(mediaController);
    vides.setVideoPath(""); 
    vides.start();
    }


 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <Button 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:text="Upload Video"
    android:id="@+id/goforuploadvid"
    />

  <Button 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:text="Delete"
    android:id="@+id/deletevid"
    android:tag="delete"
    />

   <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/video_frame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

   <VideoView 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/videoviewfull"
   />
  </FrameLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Where is your video url ?

Comment: check my question now borhter

Comment: Please move mediaController code after vides initialization.

Comment: i did you can see it in my edited question..but its not working yet

Comment: have you check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410834/android-sdk-media-player-load-video-stream-from-http-url

Comment: @kaushik i dont understand what you saying

Comment: @HareshChhelana i found one mistake there i added view pager also..i removed it..and now below delete button black portion is displaying and one alert message pop up and displaying can't play this video..can you tell me whats mistake i am making?

Comment: Try other video url ?

Comment: i removed .start method...but still it display same msg..cant i get view of video?

Comment: @HareshChhelana same output is showing still no change..can you help

Comment: can you please post xml code ?

Comment: sure brother..just now i change my xml code and added frame layout..

Comment: see my edited question you can see all change

Comment: the alert mseeage can't play this video is not showing now after made changes..see my change code in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your given video url is not correct so please use another one and when play video from url use setVideoPath(url) instead setVideoURI(uri) which generally used play video from device local :

```
vides.setVideoPath("http://download.itcuties.com/teaser/itcuties-teaser-480.mp4");
```

Instead :

```
vides.setVideoURI(uri);
```